# Interesting Binomial identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Fix $n,\ell, b \in \mathbb{N}$ with $2b\le n.$ Set $r=\min\{n-2b,\ell\}.$ Then
$$\binom{n}{\ell} \sum_{i=0}^{r}(-1)^{i}\binom{n-i}{2b}\binom{\ell}{i} = {\binom{n}{2b}}\sum_{i=0}^{\ell}\binom{b}{i}\binom{b}{\ell-i}$$
The two formulas are (different) solutions of the same combinatorial problem. Although, I am wondering how we can prove this analytically.

Comment: Could you include the combinatorial problem mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left sum reduces to $\binom{n-\ell}{2b-\ell}$, and the right sum reduces (via Vandermonde's identity) to $\binom{2b}{\ell}$.  So the LHS and RHS are equal because of the known identity $$\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k}=\binom{n}{m}\binom{m}{k}.$$

Here's a generating function approach for the left sum:
\begin{align}
\sum_n \left(\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{\ell}{i} \binom{n-i}{2b}\right)z^n
&=\left(\sum_n (-1)^n \binom{\ell}{n}z^n\right)\left(\sum_n \binom{n}{2b}z^n\right)\\
&=(1-z)^\ell \frac{z^{2b}}{(1-z)^{2b+1}} \\
&=\frac{z^{2b}}{(1-z)^{2b-\ell+1}} \\
&=\sum_n \binom{n-\ell}{2b-\ell}z^n
\end{align}

Comment: Can you elaborate a little, why the left sum reduces to $\binom{n-\ell}{2b-\ell}$?

Comment: I added snake oil to my answer.

Comment: In the first equality(RHS), both parentheses must have $n$? Maybe the first must have $i$

Comment: You can use whatever dummy summation index you want.  It is the product of two generating functions.  See [Cauchy product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Comment: sure, but from what I've read for snail oil, you have to interchange summation, and the one sum has $i$ and the other (the inner sum) has the free variable $n.$ where is this step in your proof?

Comment: OK, I guess snake oil does not really apply here. Instead, I recognized the sum as a convolution and used a product of generating functions.